# users.settings.sendAs.update does not accept characters outside of ANSI codepage and quits with an error

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I'm trying to set a signature that contains non ANSI characters, for example ñ and é, as soon as such a character is present in the JSON message, I receive an exception back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected end of string. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n\n^",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected end of string. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n\n^",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "parseError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I have tried to encode the characters via HTML encoding (i.e. `&241;`) this gets auto-escaped by the api to `&amp;241;` and is therefore useless!

Weirdly this exact request works via the API Testing page https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/update

Comment: Can you share the request you are making and how are you making it? Avoid providing personal information.

Comment: Thanks for that, it prompted me to check out the request more details and repeat it via curl!

The issue was that I was using string.length, which resulted in 1 bytes too little for the data, worked around it with new Buffer ..

Answer (score 0):

This was due to using string.length, instead of first encoding the content in a buffer and then using the buffer.length for the Content-Length!